# get mimetype of file as a string (imap_fetchbody)

Tags: php, linux, imap

You can do this if the file is a file in the filesystem:

```
shell_exec("file -bi $file")
```

But how can you do it if the file is a string (not yet saved as a file)?

The string/file is extracted from an email with `imap_fetchbody()`

## edit

```
$body = imap_fetchbody($this->stream, $this->msgno, $section);

$finfo = new finfo(FILEINFO_MIME);
echo $finfo->buffer($body) . "\n";

$file = Init::$dynamic['data_path'].$this->msgno.'_'.$part->dparameters[0]->value;
imap_savebody($this->stream, $file, $this->msgno, $section);

echo $finfo->file($file) . "\n";
```

both `$finfo->buffer()` and `$finfo->file()` returns `text/plain; charset=us-ascii` even if its PDF, PNG etc.?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`finfo_buffer`](http://php.net/finfo_buffer)

Comment: it is always returning `text/plain; charset=us-ascii` even if its PDF, PNG etc

Comment: Have you dumped out $body to see what's actually in it?

Comment: I works now.. somehow attachment 1 = part 2, attachment 2 = part 3 etc :)